# Timeout Akka Streams Flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to use `completionTimeout` in an akka streams flow. I've provided a contrived example where the flow takes 10 seconds but I've added a `completionTimeout` with a timeout of 1 second. I would expect this flow to timeout after 1 second. However, in the example the flow completes in 10 seconds without any errors.

Why doesn't the flow timeout? Is there a better way to timeout a flow?

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

class Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")

  "This Test" should "fail but passes and I don't know why" in {

    //This takes 10 seconds to complete
    val flow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = Flow[String]
        .map(str => {
          println(s"Processing ${str}")
          Thread.sleep(10000)
        })
        .map(_ => {"Done!"})

    val future: Future[String] =
      Source.single("Input")
        .via(flow)
        .completionTimeout(1 second) // Set a timeout of 1 second
        .runWith(Sink.last)

    val result = Await.result(future, 15 seconds)

    result should be("Done!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In executing a given stream, Akka Stream leverages [operator fusion](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html?language=scala#operator-fusion) to fuse stream operators by a single underlying actor for optimal performance.  For your main thread to catch the timeout, you could introduce asynchrony by means of `.async`:

```
val future: Future[String] =
  Source.single("Input")
    .via(flow)
    .async  // <--- asynchronous boundary
    .completionTimeout(1 second)
    .runWith(Sink.last)

future.onComplete(println)
// Processing Input
// Failure(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The stream has not been completed in 1 second.)
```

An alternative to introduce asynchrony is to use the [mapAsync](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html) flow stage:

```
val flow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = Flow[String]
  .map(str => {
    println(s"Processing ${str}")
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  })
  .mapAsync(1)(_ => Future("Done!"))  // <--- asynchronous flow stage
```

Despite getting the same timeout error, you may notice it'll take ~10s to see result when using `mapAsync`, whereas only ~1s using `async`.  That's because while `mapAsync` introduces an asynchronous flow stage, it's not an asynchronous boundary (like what `async` does) and is still subject to operator fusion.